# How can I use AutoLayout to place view exactly above other?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, interface-builder

I have a layout which has a `UIScrollView` which has certain constraints with its container (the root view).

[image]

Now I want to place an `UIImageView` exactly above this scrollview and place a large image inside it, which should be scaled accordingly. 
I set up constraints between the imageview and the scrollview to align their centers and make them equally wide and high. The image shows, what I would like to achieve.

[image]

What I would like is that the scrollview is fixed before the imageview is placed so that the scrollview determines the frame of the imageview on top, but what seems to happen is that the imageview (whose image resolution is too large for the screen) determines the frame of the scrollview, resulting in complete mayhem.

[image]

How can I make it so the scrollview gets the frame shown in the first image and the imageview is properly positioned on top of it?

*EDIT*: I uploaded the storyboard [here](http://pastebin.com/eaUUWCf6) (without constraints on the image view as they don't work)

Comment: You could try making the priority of the height/width constraints on the scroll view as high as you can and lowering the priority of the other constraints. I'm not 100% sure that will work, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Good idea, but that does not seem to do anything.

Comment: Try to reverse first and second item of the constraints that make them equally wide and high.

Comment: @GonjiDev Does nothing, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm sorry but I need to take a look at the storyboard to help you. Probably you're missing something

Comment: @GonjiDev I put the storyboard here: http://pastebin.com/eaUUWCf6

Comment: OK I updated the file: http://pastebin.com/bWr3Zscf don't know if it is actually what you need!

Comment: @GonjiDev Well, the image still extends to somewhere beyond the screen, so no.